# Getting 504 gateway timeout error when accessing node application through haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am facing following situations when configuring haproxy with node/express application. I am trying to
achieve following.

```
    (https)         (http)
```

browser ======> haproxy =====> node application

When loading the node application through the browser I am getting http 504 gateway time-out error.

Below is my haproxy configurtions.
[haproxy configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Pf5.png)

Following are the haproxy logs.

```
vm-2 haproxy[21255]: 127.0.0.1:45948 [23/Dec/2019:10:57:51.411] https-in~ servers/server1 0/0/0/-1/100001 504 194 - - sH-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
vm-2 haproxy[21255]: 127.0.0.1:45948 [23/Dec/2019:10:57:51.411] https-in~ servers/server1 0/0/0/-1/100001 504 194 - - sH-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
vm-2 haproxy[21255]: 127.0.0.1:46122 [23/Dec/2019:10:59:31.435] https-in~ servers/server1 0/0/0/-1/100002 504 194 - - sH-- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're haproxy logs indicate that it's taking over 100 seconds (ie 100001/100002) for the request to complete and that it's being aborted (ie -1) before your backend server can send the full response.

If you're looking for a strictly haproxy solution (ie. you can't/won't tune your application) then you would need to play with haproxy timeout settings.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem, the client requests to the server were 504s sent by the HAProxy. We found out that the `defaults` configurations in the `haproxy.cfg` file had the `timeout server` property that defined the 504 response (setting it to a lower value, `1s` in our case, would automatically result in a 504). Increasing that value is a way to have a longer connection between the proxy and the backend.